Building Reusable Blazor Components - Seeking Advice
I recently built a Blazor Server app using the Radzen master-detail data grid component (https://blazor.radzen.com/master-detail-hierarchy). To improve reusability, I'd like to turn this functionality into a custom Blazor component.
Your expertise would be greatly appreciated in understanding best practices for building reusable components, specifically:
Dynamic Data Columns: How can I structure the component to allow for flexible configuration of data columns through parameters, eliminating the need for manual RadzenDataGridColumns definition?
Parameterization for Behavior and Appearance: What are effective strategies to parameterize the component to control features like paging, sorting, and styling?

Currently, I populate the grid from a database and manually add columns. Ideally, I'd like to define columns through parameters.
I believe creating a reusable master-detail grid component would significantly enhance my development workflow. Any insights you can share would be incredibly valuable.
Thank you for your time and consideration.
<RadzenDataGrid @ref="_grid" AllowFiltering="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" AllowSorting="false" RowClick="RowClick" ExpandMode="DataGridExpandMode.Single"
                Data="@_ordersDto" TItem="OrderDto" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Single" RowUpdate="@OnUpdateRow" RowCreate="@OnCreateRow" @bind-Value="@SelectedOrders"
                ShowExpandColumn="false" ShowPagingSummary="true" AllowColumnResize="true" >
<Template Context="order">
    <RadzenDataGrid @ref="_gridDetail" AllowFiltering="@(_detailToInsert == null)" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" AllowSorting="@(_detailToInsert == null)" Data="@order.OrderDetailsDto"
                    TItem="OrderDetailDto" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Multiple" RowUpdate="@OnUpdateRowDetail" RowCreate="@OnCreateRowDetail" AllowColumnResize="true"
                                        AllowColumnPicking="true" ShowPagingSummary="true" ColumnWidth="150px" Density="Density.Compact" >
        <Columns>

        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetailDto" Property="Id" Title="Product ID" Frozen="true" OrderIndex="1"/>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetailDto" Property="ProductCode" Title="Product  Code" OrderIndex="2"/>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetailDto" Property="Warehouse" Title="Warehouse" OrderIndex="3"/>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetailDto" Property="Currency" Title="Currency" OrderIndex="4"/>
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetailDto" Property="Quantity" Title="Quantity" OrderIndex="5"/>

        </Columns>
    </RadzenDataGrid>
</Template>
<Columns>
    <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDto" Property="Id" Title="Order ID" Width="120px"/>
    <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDto" Property="OrderDateTime" Title="Order Date" Width="200px" Filterable="false"/>        
    <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDto" Property="Status" Title="Status" Width="100px"/>
        
</Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>

@code {

    IQueryable<OrderDto?> _ordersDto;
    IQueryable<Order?> _order;
    RadzenDataGrid<OrderDto?> _grid;
    RadzenDataGrid<OrderDetailDto> _gridDetail;
    IList<OrderDto?> SelectedOrders { get; set; }
    OrderDetailDto? _detailToInsert;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("************ Orders Preparing... ************");
        
        user = (await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()).User;

        //userName = user.Identity.Name;
        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Identity/Account/Login", false);
        }
        if (DataLoading)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            DataLoading = true;
            _order = ViewOrdersUseCase.Execute(user);
            _ordersDto = Mapper.ProjectTo<OrderDto>(_order);
            
           
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Message);
            
        }
        finally
        {
            DataLoading = false;
        }
        SelectedOrders = new List<OrderDto?> { _ordersDto.FirstOrDefault() };
        
    }
}

